# Consequence of trace theorem

Tags: finite-element-method

Trace theorem says that there exists unique continous linear mapping $\gamma : W^{k,p}(\varOmega) \rightarrow L^q(\varOmega)$ that $\gamma(u) = u|_{\partial \varOmega}$.

It is correct to write $||u||_{L_q(\partial \varOmega)} = ||\gamma(u)||_{W^{k,p}(\varOmega)}$? I think that that is what the theorem says, if I understand right. By the way, I am trying to prove $||u||_{L^q(\partial \varOmega)} \leq c ||u||_{W^{k,p}(\varOmega)}$ and I am using the equality above to prove.

Comment: $||\gamma(u)||_{W^{k,p}(\varOmega)}$ is wierd since $\gamma(u)$ is defined on $\partial \Omega$ and the $||.||_{W^{k,p}(\varOmega)}$ norm is not defined there. Maybe some typo somewhere?